# Out of memory exception when using xlsx module with large files

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, xlsx

I am trying to get number of rows and columns present in excel sheet

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx')
let dothis= (path) =>{
    let workbook = xlsx.readFile(path)
    let sheetsList = workbook.SheetNames

    for (let i in sheetsList) {
        var ref = workbook.Sheets[sheetsList[i]]["!ref"];
        var range = xlsx.utils.decode_range(ref);
        console.log(range);
    }
}
dothis('../storage/1million records- Copy.xlsx')
```

If the file contains less number of records then this is working fine. But if it contains 1million records I am getting the following error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10020:00000000004E7540]    88573 ms: Mark-sweep 1110.2 (1341.3) ->
1110.2 (1341.3) MB, 4542.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested [10020:00000000004E7540]    92546 ms: Mark-sweep
1110.2 (1341.3) -> 1110.2 (1326.3) MB, 3973.0 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested [10020:00000000004E7540]    97207 ms: Mark-sweep 1110.2 (1326.3) -> 1110.2 (1317.8) MB, 4660.5 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000350676A57C1 <JSObject>
    1: parse_ws_xml_data [e:\eg\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:~12315] [pc=00000280234400A9](this=000003CD0C00C211 <JSGlobal Object>,sdata=000002BA7A4A2089 <Very long string[287008182]>,s=000002BA7A4A21B1 <Object map = 00000294315E5519>,opts=000003279F33D969 <Object map = 00000294315E5CA9>,guess=000002BA7A4A2189 <Object map = 00000294315E9401>,themes=000003279F33DA41 <Object map = 00000294315...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: node_module_register  2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory  3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory  4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray  5: v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::AtPut 6: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::IsKey 7: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::IsKey 8: v8::internal::LookupIterator::ApplyTransitionToDataProperty  9: v8::internal::JSReceiver::class_name 10: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance 11: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance 12: 00000280232843C1
```

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: @RobertMennell Its v8.10.0

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: Size is about 50mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to run your script using --max-old-space-size flag and allocate more memory.

```
node --max-old-space-size=8000 hello.js
```

will allocate 8GB memory to the current running instance.

Comment: Is this still a problem in Node > 6?